# Starting from a Particular Array Index with Twig

Tags: php, twig

I have one question related to handling arrays with the Twig template engine: I would like to use an array in Twig but only display data from the array starting from a specified array index.

In PHP, I can start from the second item of an array, like this:

```
$alphabet = array("a","b","c","d");
for ($i = 1; $i < count($alphabet); $i++){
    echo($alphabet[$i]);
}
```

How can I do something similar with Twig?

For now, I can only come up with this:

```
{% for letter in alphabet %}
{{ letter }}
{%endfor}
```

but the result displays "a,b,c,d".

*But I just want to display "b,c,d".*

Is this possible to do with Twig?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use `slice` ([documentation here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html)) to do this sort of thing:

```
{% for letter in alphabet[1:] %}
{{ letter }}
{% endfor %}
```

In the example above, `[1:]` essentially means:

> *"start at the second array index and keep going until the very end of the array"*.

Another way to look at the `slice` filter is like this:

```
[start:length]
```

- `start`: array index from which to start
- `length`: how much of the array to display

Comment: Thank you for your help.that's what I want !!

Comment: @whitebear Glad to hear it :)